# Installing Ubuntu onto other hard drive

Tags: system-installation

I am a total beginner to Linux. I d/l a legit Ubuntu 14.0 onto a memory stick, and want to install it onto a 160gb hdd I have attached to my PC running XP Pro. I can launch the "try me" no problem, but when I try to fully install Ubuntu, using the "something else" option, I am presented with a "Installation Type" screen. I have tried a number of combinations of response, but when I hit "install now", I immediately get a warning screen telling me "No root system is defined. Please correct this from the partitioning menu". The drive was formatted on Win Xp as Fat32.
Can anyone please walk me through the setup?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**Update for Ubuntu 18.04 and above**

New installations of recent versions of Ubuntu does not use a separate swap partition any more. They use a swap file by default.

**Original Answer**

Ubuntu installation needs two partitions in their own formats. It won't work with FAT32.

1. Make sure you don't have any any important data in the external hard
   drive. If you do, copy them some place else. After you select **Something else**, **make sure you are modifying your external hard drive and not the internal one.** The internal drive is usually `/dev/sda`. The external one can be `/dev/sdb` or `/dev/sdc` or something else.
2. Delete the existing FAT32 partition in the external hard drive.
3. Create two partitions. The first is called `/`. This is the main
   partition where Ubuntu will be installed. Create format this
   partition `ext4`. Leave 2 to 4 GB space in the end for the next
   partition.
4. The second partition is called `Swap`. This is used as virtual
   memory. Use the remaining 2 to 4 GB space to create this partition.
   It should have the partition type `Linux-Swap`. It does not have any
   mount point.

Make sure **Device for bootloader installation:** at the bottom points to your external hard drive. It can be `/dev/sdb` or `dev/sdc` or something else.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simple and is clear:

> No root system is defined. Please correct this from the partitioning menu

In order to install ubuntu you should define 4  partitions:

1. One is a swap area should be double the size of the RAM.
2. For the root system and should be something from 10 to 20 GB.
3. For the home directory to be installed and can be anything (you choose according to your needs).
4. For the Grub and it should be at least 1MB

To add these just select the appropriate one from the list:[partition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dn3Vt.png)

In the Image the `/` stands for root.

You might also want to check this post: http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html